# How to move every group of rows to a new column?

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I'd like to move every group of rows to columns this way.

Input:

```
R1C1
R2C1
R3C1
R1C2
R2C2
R3C2
R1C3
R2C3
R3C3
```

Output:

```
R1C1 R1C2 R1C3
R2C1 R2C2 R2C3
R3C1 R3C2 R3C3
```

I'm also adding actual example with some number below.

Input:

```
8.097e-10
7.099e-10
6.638e-10
6.395e-10
6.258e-10
6.180e-10
6.134e-10
6.108e-10
6.093e-10
```

Output:

```
8.097e-10 6.395e-10 6.134e-10
7.099e-10 6.258e-10 6.108e-10
6.638e-10 6.180e-10 6.093e-10
```

Comment: Have you actually tried anything?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [pr](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/pr-invocation.html) command:

```
pr -T -3 input_file > output_file
```

- `-3` means there'll be 3 columns
- `-T` omits pagination of output

Answer (score 3):

If you *really* need to do it with awk, then maybe use an array indexed by the record number modulo 3

```
awk '{i = (NR-1)%3; a[i] = a[i]? a[i] OFS $0 : $0} END{for(i=0;i<3;i++) print a[i]}' file
R1C1 R1C2 R1C3
R2C1 R2C2 R2C3
R3C1 R3C2 R3C3
```

If the `rs` (**r**e**s**hape) utility is available, then

```
rs 0 3 < file | rs -T
```

or

```
paste - - - < file | rs -c -T
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat test.txt
R1C1
R2C1
R3C1
R1C2
R2C2
R3C2
R1C3
R2C3
R3C3

$ awk '{Arr[substr($0,1,2)]=Arr[substr($0,1,2)]" "$0}END{for (i in Arr){print Arr[i]}}' test.txt
 R1C1 R1C2 R1C3
 R2C1 R2C2 R2C3
 R3C1 R3C2 R3C3
```